# Select only .tif files in scene, Maya-Python

Tags: python, file, attributes, maya

I'm trying to create a small tool where I select all the files (textures) in my scene and apply a specific filter to them.
I get the list of `'.fileTextureName'` attributes that exist on my scene and I get every .`exr` and `.tif` that I have. But I am trying to remove the `.exr` from my list and only apply the filter only to the `.tif`. 
I haven't find a way to make a list of the attributes or to select just the type of file I want.

Here is just the begining of the script:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

allFileNodes = cmds.ls(type="file")

def attrList():
    for eachFile in allFileNodes:

        currentFile = cmds.getAttr(eachFile + '.fileTextureName')
        print currentFile


attrList()
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're simply wanting to filter what to operate on based on its file extension then you can use `.endswith` to only include tif extensions:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

all_file_nodes = cmds.ls(type="file")

for each_file in all_file_nodes:
    image_path = cmds.getAttr(each_file + ".fileTextureName")  # Get the image's path the file is referencing.
    if image_path.lower().endswith(".jpg"):  # Only continue if the image ends with `tif`, we include `.lower()` in case the extension is upper case.
        print image_path  # Only tifs beyond this point, do what you want.
```

Comment: Awesome @GreenCell ! This worked perfectly ! I didn't know you could add `.endswith` to a variable. Is there any documentation where I can find these kind of commands nad how to use them? I'm still fairly new to python and haven't been able to find these kind of thigs.
Thank you so much!

Comment: `image_path` is a normal string, so `endswith` and `lower` are native string methods in Python. This page has some info on other methods you can use with strings: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_string.asp